# How do I make backslash (\) work in IDLE?

Tags: python, macos, python-idle, backslash

I use a Mac and I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> when I want to type a `\`. I'm trying to learn Python and as you can see \ works fine, but not in IDLE.

How do I make backslash (\) work in IDLE?

Comment: "but not in IDLE"?  What does that mean?  How does \\ fail to work in IDLE?  What happens that's incorrect?

Comment: @Kris, maybe it's just me, but I cannot figure out what you want to do with the backslash. Print it out? Or use it as a line break in source code?

Comment: I think he's saying that his keyboard doesn't have a backslash key, and the usual keyboard shortcut, Shift-Alt-/, doesn't type a backslash in IDLE.

Comment: It's been a while since I used a Mac, but the ones I used all had a backslash key, in the same standard spot that PCs do. If you're missing such a key, it probably has more to do with what country you're from.

Comment: @sm I should have mentioned it. I use it with \n and \t

Comment: @S.Lott Thank you! That works. Why didn't I think of that?!

Comment: @Kris: "That works"?  What works?  What problem do you have?  What happens that's incorrect?  I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @S.Lott , I needed a way to type \ in IDLE. It works on my Mac (when I use shift + alt + / ) but not when I try to do it in IDLE. The solution is to type it somewhere else and then copy and paste it in IDLE.

Answer (score 9):

Since this problem still persists on OSX 10.8 with python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2 and since this is the first google hit when searching for backslash idle here is a more practical solution instead of copy and pasting:
Go to:

```
idle->preferences->keys
```

Under Action-Keys replace:

```
expand-word <Option-Key-Slash>
```

with something you like for instance:

```
expand-word <Control-Option-Key-Slash>
```

This should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Run into this problem today and your answer fixed it perfectly and super easy

Answer (score 0):

Copy-Paste it from notepad.
    *or*
Use command line python shell.

Comment: copy and paste, that's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

go to

> idle -> preferences -> General -> default source encoding -> Locale-defined

Answer (score 0):

In IDLE, it worked with <kbd>alt (option)</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone i have an excellent solution to this problem.
Go to "Terminal":

Write

`Python`

Now it works because it's like using IDLE just in terminal and in terminal the backslash will work perfectly fine.